# Crash validating iOS receipts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I released a game on the App Store, and I'm getting several crashes in the following code while verifying receipts:

```
-(BOOL)isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (!(transaction && transaction.transactionReceipt && [transaction.transactionReceipt length] > 0))
    {
        // Transaction is not valid.
        return NO;
    }

    // Pull the purchase-info out of the transaction receipt, decode it, and save it for later so
    // it can be cross checked with the verifyReceipt.
    NSDictionary *receiptDict       = [self dictionaryFromPlistData:transaction.transactionReceipt];
    NSString *transactionPurchaseInfo = [receiptDict objectForKey:@"purchase-info"];

    ...
```

The issue is that `receiptDict` is not a `NSDictionary`, so the code crashes down the road.  How can this be? Is there some other form the `transaction.transactionReceipt` can take? An error?

It's happen very rarely, maybe 1% of my users that try and buy something? Is this result of people hacking it?

I've put a check in to make sure it's and `NSDictionary`, but of there is a deeper issue, I'd like to find that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as [developer.apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states

> The contents of this property are undefined except when
>   transactionState is set to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased.

So you should always check the `transactionState` of the transaction, if the transaction state is equal to `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` then you can get the data from `transactionReceipt` as a dictionary.

Also consider that the data sent and received from App store is JSON format and you should use a JSON parser to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

We've just added receipt validation to our projects. You can check out the ios version here: https://github.com/soomla/ios-store